# Pointer issues in Coccinelle

Tags: c, static-analysis, coccinelle

I want to change my code using a [Coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/rules/) script:

```
// Before modification

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int *p;

    *p=i;

    return 0;
}
```

The expected result is:

```
// After modification

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int *p;

    if (p!=NULL)
        *p=i;

    return 0;
}
```

My Coccinelle script is as follows:

```
@rule1@
type T;
T* ptr;
expression E;
@@

-*ptr= E;
+ if (ptr!=NULL)
+ptr=E;
```

My script is wrong because the "star" operator is used by Coccinelle. Could anyone help me to know for what the "star" operator is useful because I am a little bit confused about this operator.  How can I modify my script to get the expected result?

Comment: The C code you presented is just an example right? Since you are reading uninitialized variables.

Comment: Your example C program would crash (if you're lucky). You're attempting to write to unallocated memory.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: And the modified version reads an uninitialized variable.

Comment: you mean `p = &i` instead of `*p = i ?` it is referred to as `pointer` a c programming book can help you.

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname See, and it even solves your star problems. :-)

Comment: Yes it could be another problem to check ,but the problem is not here the problem consists in pattern matching a line that contains "star operator"

Comment: I tried to escape * by a backslash \* but still not working i got this error Fatal error: exception Lexer_cocci.Lexical ("unrecognised symbol, in token rule:\")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a space before the *.

Coccinelle uses * to indicate that a match is wanted, rather than a transformation.  The * indicates a line that should be highlighted in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the `*` operator is used by cocinelle for pattern matching, `x*` would match several occurrences of `x` in a row.

I would try to escape the `*` with a backslash `\*`.

Also, the `*` is missing from your replacement pattern, I think.

Comment: In the Coccinelle script above i escaped * with backslash \* but i got an error :Fatal error: exception Lexer_cocci.Lexical ("unrecognised symbol, in token rule:\")